# What is wrong here "Check the render method of `App`." anyone help me, pls?

Tags: reactjs

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Navbar.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'; 
import './Navbar.css'; 
import logo from '../Assets/Img/logo-Ci.png'; 
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Navbar = () => {
const [menu,setMenu] = useState("Home")


return (
    <div className="container-nav">
        <div className='navbar'>
            <div className='nav-logo'>
                <img src={logo} alt="logo-cellinfo" />
            </div>
            <ul className='nav-menu'>
                <li onClick = {() => {setMenu("Home")}}><Link to="/">Home</Link>{menu==="Home"?<hr/>:<></>}</li>
                <li onClick = {() => {setMenu("About us")}}><Link to="/">About us</Link>{menu==="About us"?<hr/>:<></>}</li>
                <li onClick = {() => {setMenu("Product")}}><Link to="/">Product</Link>{menu==="Product"?<hr/>:<></>}</li>
                <li onClick = {() => {setMenu("Service")}}><Link to="/">Service</Link>{menu==="Service"?<hr/>:<></>}</li>
                <li onClick = {() => {setMenu("Compare")}}><Link to="/">Compare</Link> {menu==="Compare"?<hr/>:<></>}</li>
            </ul>
            <div className="nav-input-search">
                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder='ex:iphone 15 pro vip'/>
                    <button className='submit'>
                        <i class="bi bi-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
)}

export default Navbar;
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Shop } from "./Pages/Shop";
import { ShopCategory } from "./Pages/ShopCategory";
import { ProductOfCellinfo } from "./Pages/PageOfCellinfo/ProductOfCellinfo";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Shop/>}/>
            <Route path='/About Us' element={<ShopCategory category="About us"/>}/>
            <Route path='/ProductOfCellinfo' element={<ShopCategory category="ProductOfCellinfo"/>}/>
            <Route path='/Service' element={<ShopCategory category="Service"/>}/>
            <Route path='/Compare' element={<ShopCategory category="Compare"/>}/>
            <Route path="/ProductOfCellinfo" element={<ProductOfCellinfo/>}>
              <Route path =':productId' element={<ProductOfCellinfo/>}/>
            </Route>
          </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
reportWebVitals();
```

I learning base on this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y99YgaQjgx4&t=1859s.

Comment: Can you check to be sure that all the other components in the App.js were exported appropriately?

Comment: When i comment "Routes", everythings is ok. So, i think this is problem but i can't find it

Comment: You can comment out each route, and that should help you isolate the route with the problem

Comment: Your problem is either with Shop, ShopCategory or ProductOfCellinfo export